# Brezis' problem 34C: an estimate $\|T u\|_{L^p(0,1)} \leq \frac{p}{p-1} \|u\|_{L^p(0,1)}$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, lp-spaces

I'm trying to solve below exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Problem 34C** In this part we set $E=L^p(0,1)$ with $1<p<\infty$. Given $u \in L^p(0,1)$ define $T u$ by
> $$
> T u(x)=\frac{1}{x} \int_0^x u(t) d t \quad \text {for } x \in(0,1] .
> $$
>
> 1. Check that $T u \in C((0,1])$ and that $T u \in L^q(0,1)$ for every $q<p$.
> 2. Prove that if $u \in C_c((0,1))$ then
>    $$
>    \|T u\|_{L^p(0,1)} \leq \frac{p}{p-1} \|u\|_{L^p(0,1)} .
>    $$

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in my below attempt of $(2)$. Could you please have a check on it?

---

1. The map $(0,1] \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is clearly continuous. By dominated convergence theorem, the map $(0,1] \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto \int_0^x u(t) d t$ is continuous. Then $T u \in C((0,1])$. By Hölder's inequality,
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   \|T u\|_{L^q}^q &= \int_0^1 \left | \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x u(t) d t \right |^q dx \\
   &=\int_0^1 \frac{\|1_{(0, x]} u\|_{L^1}^q}{x^q}  dx \\
   &\le\int_0^1 \frac{\|1_{(0, x]}\|_{L^{p^*}}^q \|u\|_{L^p}^q}{x^q}  dx \\
   &=\|u\|_{L^p}^q \int_0^1 x^{-\frac{q}{p}} dx,
   \end{align*}
   $$
   where $p^*$ is the Hölder conjugate of $p$. If $q<p$ then $\int_0^1 x^{-\frac{q}{p}} dx < \infty$.
2. Let $\varphi (x) = \int_0^x u(t) d t$ for $x \in [0, 1]$. By FTC, $\varphi' (x) = u(x)$. Because $p \in (1, \infty)$, we get $(| \cdot|^p)' (x) =p | x|^{p-1} \operatorname{sgn} (x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. By chain rule, $(| \varphi|^p)' (x) =p | \varphi (x)|^{p-1} \operatorname{sgn} (\varphi (x)) u(x)$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$. Then $| \varphi|^p \in C^1 ([0, 1])$. By change of variable $x \mapsto -x^{1-p}$, we get
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   \int_0^1|T u(x)|^p d x &=\int_0^1|\varphi(x)|^p \frac{d x}{x^p} \\
   &=\frac{1}{p-1} \int_0^1 |\varphi(x)|^p d\left(-x^{1-p}\right).
   \end{align*}
   $$

By integration by parts, we get
$$
\begin{align*}
(p-1) \int_0^1|T u(x)|^p d x &= - \frac{|\varphi(x)|^p}{x^{p-1}} \bigg |_0^1 +  \int_0^1 \frac{d(|\varphi(x)|^p)}{x^{p-1}} \\
&=- |\varphi(1)|^p + p \int_0^1 \frac{p|\varphi(x)|^{p-1} \operatorname{sgn} (\varphi (x)) u(x)}{x^{p-1}}  dx \\
&= - |\varphi(1)|^p + p \int_0^1 |Tu (x)|^{p-1} u(x) \operatorname{sgn} (\varphi (x)) dx.
\end{align*}
$$

By Hölder's inequality,
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 |Tu (x)|^{p-1} u(x) \operatorname{sgn} (\varphi (x)) dx &\le \left ( \int_0^1 |Tu (x)|^{(p-1) p^*}\right )^{1 / p^*}  \|u\|_{L^p} \\
&=\|Tu\|_{L^p}^{p-1} \|u\|_{L^p}.
\end{align*}
$$

Then
$$
(p-1) \|Tu\|_{L^p}^p \le - |\varphi(1)|^p + p \|Tu\|_{L^p}^{p-1} \|u\|_{L^p}.
$$

Then
$$
0 \le |\varphi(1)|^p \le \|Tu\|_{L^p}^{p-1} (p \|u\|_{L^p} - (p-1)\|Tu\|_{L^p}).
$$

Then $(p-1)\|Tu\|_{L^p} \le p \|u\|_{L^p}$. The claim then follows.